# Does $N(T)^{\bot}$ have finite dimension when $T:H\rightarrow V,$ where $H$ is Hilbert space and $V$ is linear space with finite dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm trying to prove or disprove the next statement, and if it's false, give conditions to satisfy it.

If $T:H\rightarrow V$ is linear and continuous transformation between a Hilbert space $H$ and a linear space $V$ such that $dim(V)=n,$ then $dim(N(T)^{\bot})=n.$

I think the previous is true. If we consider $T:H\rightarrow\mathbb{C} $ as in the statment we have that if $N(T)^{\bot}\neq 0,$ then because of the projection theorem $dim(N(T)^{\bot})=1.$

My feeling is the above holds for $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ but I'm stuck. Even if it's true, how can I prove the original statement?

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: Hint: Show and use that $T: N(T)^\perp \rightarrow V$ is injective. Note also that it need not be surjective (so your bound may be an inequality).

Comment: Thanks for answer @H.H.Rugh. As $N(T)^{\bot}$ is a subspace of V, then $dim(N(T)^{\bot})\leq dim(V)=n.$ So it's not need to prove the map is inyective, isn'it?

Comment: $N(T)^\perp$ is a subspace of $H$ but it has the same dimension as its image (as $T$ is injective on that subspace). The map $T$ as such is not injective but it must be injective on $N(T)^\perp$. Do you see why?

Comment: I see that $N(T)^{\bot}$ is a subspace of $H$, but I don't get why that map is injective.

Comment: Well, if $Tv_1=Tv_2$ with $v_1,v_2\in N(T)^\perp$ then $v=v_1-v_2$ maps to the zero vector. But then $v\in N(T)$ as well so $v=0$ and $v_1=v_2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @H.H.Rugh! Your answer has been very helpful.